# how to add the same header and footer on all activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

how can i add the same header on all activity minus the active activity and a footer on all activities.the header is more like a dashboard activity so the user doesnt need to go back the dashboard to enter new activity and header has back and/or home buttons too for going back the previous activity for easier moving in and out of activities.example i have 5 activities and im in activity 4 right now so the header displays a button for activity 1,2,3,5 so when i click those button i go on its respective activity.footer can just be all text.just to show the name of activity.header is on top of all activities while footer is at bottom just want to clear this out

Comment: Can you show us codes on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: im still searching for header or actionbar codes right now.but i do have all activities with intents just missing the header bar and footer bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

1. Create an abstract base activity which will be extended by all of your activities.

inside onCreate() of your base activity do setContentView(R.layout.baseLayout). The base layout will look something similar to this,

```
<LinearLayout>

    <Header/> /*incldue your header layout here*/
    <LinearLayout id="+id/Container"> /*this viewGroup will act as a container for all other activities to load it's specific layout*/
    <Footer/> /*include your footer layout here*/

</LinerLayout>
```

2) Now start creating your other activites(1,2,3,4,5) and inflate specific layouts into base activities container.

3) have your common implementations done in your base activity so you don't duplicate the code.

4) for example, create abstract methods in your base class like setFooter(String activityName) and override in each activity by passing specific names for the footer.

Let me know if this helps or you need more details.

Comment: actually i do need more help can your atleast show me how to do those things?steps are clear but i have problems with codes.

Comment: I can help if you can provide your existing code.

Comment: ok il show you the first activity its a profile thing im still working on it coz it looks bad on landscape orrientation but its ok now with portrait.dont run location im still working on it i needs to be service they say so its wrong here it is http://pastebin.com/9kvLFg5k